Interpreting signal from plethysmography sensor
I have a plethysmography sensor by ADI Instruments, connected to a Biosemi ActiveTwo device. My goal is to measure heart rate, in the context of a social psychology lab experiment to investigate reactions to certain stimuli. The sensor produces a signal, but I have trouble interpreting it. My question is whether I need to apply some transformation to the signal, or if I'm misunderstanding what type of sensor this is, if the placement of the sensor is wrong or if the sensor is perhaps faulty.
The device is described in the manual as "an infrared photoelectric sensor to detect changes in tissue blood volume". The specifications are:



Specifications





Excitation
6 to 9 V DC


Output
5 to 50 mV (typical finger application at rest)


Output imp
1 kΩ nominal



The readings I get are as follows. The marks on the x axis (24-32) represent seconds. You can see very small pointy spikes that are approximately twice the frequency of my heart rate, for example one exactly on the 26 mark, one midway between 26 and 27, and one exactly on 27. Is this the heart rate and should I somehow extract those spikes? I tried various Y scales in ActiView (in the screenshot 500 uV is shown) but that didn't make much of a difference in how interpretable the signal was.

I expected it to look like either of the two signals below (CC BY-SA 3.0, from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:VenousPulsationAnd_PGG.png):

This is how I applied the sensor. I tried various other positions (higher and lower, and on different fingers) but that didn't make much of a difference. The sensor clearly reacts to being applied or removed though, this causes huge jumps for a short time.
I also tried to use the sensor in complete darkness except for my laptop screen (lights switched off in a room with no windows) but that didn't make a difference.

The inside looks like this:

So, to repeat my questions:

Do I need to apply some transformation to the signal?
Am I misunderstanding what type of sensor this is and what the signal represents?
Is the placement of the sensor wrong?
Is the sensor is perhaps faulty or over/undersensitive?

